# Help me build my blaster sorcerer!

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

I'm gearing up for the second half of a campaign based on the idea of Law vs Chaos. I opted for Law. However, instead of playing a Wizard like I normally do, I'm going to give the Sorcerer a shot. In keeping with playing outside my comfort zone, I'm opting to play a blaster.

For the purposes of this, assume I'm using the elite array of stats. This character is starting at level 21 with appropriate wealth by level.

Books **not** allowed: Psionics, Tome of Magic, Tome of Battle. Everything else, including setting books, BoED and BoVD, and one-off books like Lords of Madness and Libris Mortis, is allowed. The only other stipulation to that rule is that, whatever I use becomes available for the DM to use as well.

Races **not** allowed: Dragon. In this game, dragons don't exist. This is non-negotiable.

*Incarnum is implemented very well, and is sort of a focus for the game.*

I have the general idea that I want to take at least 3 levels of Archmage (for Mastery of Elements, Mastery of Shaping, and Arcane Fire). I'm not set in stone on this decision, and I'm willing to hear any ideas.

If Incarnum, or the fact that this character is Lawful going against the forces of Chaos, can be implemented to make him a better blaster, I'd appreciate it a lot. There's not a lot of support for Incarnum, unfortunately.

Comment: Since so many of these things require gm approval, how does your DM feel about Races of the Dragon and kobolds? There are some cute things you can do as a kobold sorcerer and meldshaping can help with that. How attached to sorcerer are you? Are you looking for blasty-casty? Or sorcerer period?

Comment: Questioner and answerers, please keep in mind our site guidance on [build questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic).

Comment: @SlatzG Just how important is a build to 21, sorcerer, and archmage to your concept? Is your intention "blaster" or "sorcerer archmage"

Comment: It has to be level 21. I wanted to try "blaster sorcerer" because both things are things I haven't done before. I'm more set on blaster, however, and will change to a different class if it would prove to be better.

Comment: @JackLesnie What do you want in particular from a canonical answer? If it is something that exists in spite of the requirements in this question, you may wish to instead open your own, new, canonical question - and if so, probably place a flag asking for a refund on your bounty.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs - Brian's answer is fantastic, and incorporates Incarnum.  But 'Blaster' is a role that a lot of people want to play - an answer(s) that incorporates the various common paths to blasting (which is difficult in 3.5e, and usually vastly inferior to buffing or battlefield control), would be beneficial for the site.  Stuff like mailman, kobold sorcerer, packing assay / true strike in with Orbs with that spel lthat lets you cast 2 spells at the same time, action economy sorc, feats that boost elemental damage, searing spell, etc.  A broad answer for 'blasting as a sorcerer'.

Comment: New question isn't a terrible idea, though.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you might be expecting the wrong thing for this question. This isn't a canonical answer question, it seems - it's a question for solving someone's specific circumstance. A canonical question would be much different, like: "Given all the books, all the races, how can I build the bestest, blastiest sorcerer? Dragons are allowed, btw. Preferably don't suggest stuff that a sensible DM would totally ban as soon as look at it, or if you do, suggest alternatives. Answers should mention elaborate on the build's milestones at level 5, 10, 15 and 20." etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Eep, a Kobold Sorcerer/Meldshaper/Soul Caster with a nice scoop of cheese.**

(in honour of my own fallen kobold 4e artificer)...

I rationalize (it's politer to say justify, but...) the cheese because you're choosing to be a blaster sorcerer, which is a niche normally reserved for people who aren't a [god](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19873034/Treantmonks_guide_to_Wizards%3a_Being_a_God&post_num=5), as well as the fact that I'm trying to stuff meldshaper into this... abomination.

Assuming you're not using any early entry feats, your minimum requirement is Sorcerer/4 Incarnate/2

Precocious Apprentice removes 3 of those necessary sorcerer levels (which we get back with [Greater Rite of Passage](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060420a). Arguments can be made both ways as to 2/2 or 1/3 class disposition. Then drop the rest into soulcaster. (note the lack of dragonwrought cheese. Even I have some standards.) The specific breakdown will be a function of your starting level and how useful you want to be early in the game. You won't get the incarnate radiance at 3rd, but since you aren't a melee type, the point is rather moot.

At 6, with Greater Draconic Rite of Passage and a 2/2 split:

Sorcerer 2+2+1 = Cast as if you're a 5th level sorcerer
Incarnate 2+2 = Shape as if you're a 4th level incarnate.

Feats: Precocious Apprentice (take a blasty spell), Incarnum Spellshaping, Draconic Reservoir

Get bonus essentia as soon as possible, metamagic, and midnight metamagic after you pass all the necessary requirements.

While this is not an astonishing build, it can serve as the basis of a very solid ray-based sorcerer (Sighting gloves are your friends) that can keep up with most parties.

Comment: This is an interesting build. I'll have to ask about Kobolds though. As one detail I seem to have forgotten is that dragons don't exist..

Comment: It might be helpful to expend on the "no Dragons" rule. Kobolds aren't Dragons as long as you don't use Dragonwrought. Draconic rite of passage similarly is just a fluff name. Edit: Ok the site just gave me this as a recent question :p. Just ignore the comment